# Is there a Python function equivalent to powertransform in R

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, scipy, transformation

Is there an python function equivalent to powertransform in R?

This is in R: `powerTransform(X, family = "bcnPower")`

I'm aware and used the following functions/packages:

```py
    from scipy.stats import skew,boxcox_normmax
    from scipy.special import boxcox, inv_boxcox
    from  scipy.stats import yeojohnson_normmax
    from scipy.stats import boxcox_llf
    from sklearn.preprocessing import power_transform
    from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
```

I'm trying to transform list(vector), using python.

```py
from scipy.stats import boxcox_normmax
vec =""" 4  5  5  6  5  5  3  7  7  6  5  5  8  8  3  2  3  5 10  6  7  5  2  3  1  3  4  4  5  2  5  4  5  6  5  4  2  6  3 10  4  7  5  2
7  7  3 11  5  4  4  2  2  4  6  3  4  5  6  5  8  7  4  3  5  7  3  3  6  5  3  6  6  3  9  7  9  7  2  4  2  6  4  2  5  3  4  2
7  3  7  5  5  1  5  7  1  4  5  7"""
vec = list(map(int,vec.split()))
print("min  val :",min(vec))
print(boxcox_normmax(vec,method="all"))
```

min  val : 1

[0.62926218 0.58382934]

```
powerTransform(vec, family="bcnPower")
```

Estimated transformation power, lambda
[1] 0.5831778

Location gamma was fixed at its lower bound
[1] 0.1

**I want python function which give the same output parameters and results.**

**If there is no such function can I implement such function and how?**

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
import pandas as pd
vec = """ 4  5  5  6  5  5  3  7  7  6  5  5  8  8  3  2  3  5 10  6  7  5  2  3  1  3  4  4  5  2  5  4  5  6  5  4  2  6  3 10  4  7  5  2
7  7  3 11  5  4  4  2  2  4  6  3  4  5  6  5  8  7  4  3  5  7  3  3  6  5  3  6  6  3  9  7  9  7  2  4  2  6  4  2  5  3  4  2
7  3  7  5  5  1  5  7  1  4  5  7"""
vec = list(map(int, vec.split()))
pt = PowerTransformer(method='box-cox', standardize=False)
data = pd.DataFrame(vec)
pt.fit(data)
print('Lambda =',pt.lambdas_)
print('First 10 elements:',pt.transform(data)[:10].reshape(1, -1))

#Lambda = [0.58382935]
#First 10 elements: [[2.13498738 2.67039083 2.67039083 3.16269828 2.67039083 2.67039083
#  1.54007639 3.62183527 3.62183527 3.16269828]]
```

`power_transform` gives the same if you set `standardize=False`.

In R:

```r
p = powerTransform(vec, family = "bcPower")
p$lambda
#      vec 
#0.5838294 
bcPower(vec, lambda=p$lambda)[1:10]
# [1] 2.134987 2.670391 2.670391 3.162698 2.670391 2.670391 1.540076
# [8] 3.621836 3.621836 3.162698
```